# Type or namespace name 'Diagnostics' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure'

Tags: azure

I'm working with a pre-existing codebase from a software developer that has left my company. I've downloaded the source code from the repository. When I attempt to build the project, I get an error that says:

```
The type or namespace name 'Diagnostics' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I can't figure out how to get this project up-and-running. When I look at the NuGet packages associated with the project, I can see that the Windows Azure Configuration Manager and Windows Azure Storage packages are already installed. I'm not sure what I'm missing though.

Can someone tell me what I need to install on my machine to get past this error? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics` added in your project?

Comment: The project has it listed. However, there is a yellow triangle with an exclamation point in it. When I look at the properties, the Aliases are listed as global. The Path field is empty.

Comment: Perhaps the .dll file that was originally used for adding the reference was moved or deleted. Does it help if you delete and re-add the reference?

Comment: If you haven't already, you'll may need to install the Windows Azure SDK (available via the Web Platform Installer).

Comment: I have installed 2.4 SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had this error.  The problem was that the project was referencing Framework 3.5 and I have the 2.4 SDK installed which targets 4.0.  Upgrade your project to target 4.0 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. This project's Azure Tools verion is 2.9.

I resolved this error by right clicking References under the project that has the error, then clicking Add Reference, then click Extensions under Assemblies. Find Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, check the box, and click OK. Now try rebuilding your project and hope for a different error.

The assembly should exist on your computer here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\plugins\Diagnostics\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll

If you do not see this assembly, it's most likely because you do not have the required Azure SDK. If you are using Azure SDK v2.9 like I am, you can download the SDKs here: [Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - 2.9](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=51657)

Then click download and select:

- MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi (Microsoft Azure Client Libraries for .NET)
- MicrosoftAzureTools.VS.140 (Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015)

If you are using Azure SDK v2.7 then you will want to use this link: [Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178)